# Причастия от глагола сберечь

Tags: глаголы, морфология

Почему нет причастия наст. вр. ни действительного, ни страдательного от глагола сберечь?

Answer (score 2):

Глагол сберечь имеет совершенный вид, то есть обозначает законченное действие, поэтому  причастия настоящего времени от него не образуются.

Действительные причастия настоящего времени образуются  от глаголов несовершенного вида, за исключением глаголов многократного действия (сиживать, сказывать).

Страдательные причастия настоящего времени образуются от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида.

Comment: Спасибо! 
<Страдательные причастия настоящего времени образуются от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида> а глагол "молоть"?

Comment: Кроме грамматических показателей, для причастий и деепричастий есть еще ФОНЕТИЧЕСКИЕ ограничения (то есть от данной основы невозможно образовать "читаемое" слово). В частности, образование страдательных причастий настоящего времени не является регулярным. Например, причастия не образуют следующие переходные глаголы несовершенного вида: брать, ждать, писать, мазать, колоть, лить, пить, шить, мыть, рыть, мять.

Answer (score 1):

SvetlanaSH, чтобы не заморачиваться в формулировках и оговорках Софии, предлагаю следующую простую. ***От глаголов соврешенного вида причастия настоящего времени не образуются***. Все. Это факт абсолютный и полностью дает ответ на Ваш вопрос.

//==================

Переходность здесь особой роли  даже не играет.
Проще всего это понять, попытавшись образовать подобные причастия от любого  распространенного приставочного глагола. Пойти - "пойдущий". Такие окказионализмы дают "причастия" будущего времени, никак не настоящего - и именно в таком значении иногда встречаются в литературе (если интересно, найду примеры; У Гумилева, помнится, было).

Рассуждать же, от чего и при каких условиях тот или иной разряд причастий образуется, можно бесконечно. Учебники обычно дают только общее представление. Абсолютных же правил тут нет. Есть даже несколько страдательных причастий, образованных от непереходных глаголов (руководимый, управляемый).

Касательно глагола *молотить*. От него страдательные причастия действительно не образуются. Причина, конечно, не столько фонетическая, сколько та, что глагол этот бесприставочный. От таких глаголов страдательные причастия обычно не образуются. Если точно, то страдательные настоящего времени - вообще (кроме единичных весьма спорных случаев, связанных, например, с морфемным переразложением - ведомый, упрекаемый и проч.). А причастия прошедшего времени, если и образуются, трактуются как отглагольные прилагательные, которые, впрочем, тоже могут выступать в роли причастий. Большинство примеров у Софии, кстати, из этого ряда: *мытый, рытый, колотый, мазан(н)ый*, - и сюда же *молотый*.

*(!)Я старался писать кратко и понятно, сколь это возможно, если где-то погрешил против формальной точности, готов исправиться.*

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!